# How do I get Ruby to search for a pattern on the tail of a local file?

Tags: ruby, unix, logging, pattern-matching, tail

Say I have a file `blah.rb` which is constantly written to somehow and has patterns like :

```
bagtagrag" " hellobello "  blah0 blah1 " trag kljesgjpgeagiafw blah2    " gneo" whatttjtjtbvnblah3
```

Basically, it's garbage. But I want to check for the blah that keeps on coming up and find the latest value i.e. number in front of the blah.

Hence, something like :

```
grep "blah"{$1} | tail var/test/log
```

My file is at location `var/test/log` and as you can see, I need to get the number in front of the blah.

```
def get_last_blah("filename")
    // Code to get the number after the last blah in the less of the filename
end

def display_the_last_blah()
    puts get_last_blah("var/test/log")
end
```

Now, I could just keep on reading the file and performing something akin to string pattern search on the entire file again and again. Obtaining the last value, I can then get the number. But what if I only want to look at the added text in the less and not the entire text.

Moreover, is there a quick one-liner or smart command to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`IO.open`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-c-open) to read the file and [`Enumerable#grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) to search the desired text using a regular expression like the following code does:

```
def get_last_blah(filename)
  open(filename) { |f| f.grep(/.*blah(\d).*$/){$1}.last.to_i }
end

puts get_last_blah('var/test/log')
# => 3
```

The method return the number in from of the last "blah" word of the file. It is reading the entire file but the result is the same as if is done with `tail`.

If you want to use a proper `tail`, take a look at the [`File::Tail`](http://flori.github.io/file-tail/) gem.

Comment: Thanks for that. I updated my question since I think I did not completely add all details. I need to grep the `tail` of a file.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you wish to avoid reading the entire file each time; rather, you want to start at the end and work backward until you find the last string of interest.  Here's a way to do that.

**Code**

```
BLOCK_SIZE = 30
MAX_BLAH_NBR = 123

def doit(fname, blah_text)
  @f = File.new(fname)
  @blah_text = blah_text
  @chars_to_read = BLOCK_SIZE + @blah_text.size + MAX_BLAH_NBR.to_s.size
  ptr = @f.size
  block_size = BLOCK_SIZE
  loop do
    return nil if ptr.zero?
    ptr -= block_size
    if ptr < 0
      block_size += ptr
      ptr = 0
    end
    blah_nbr = read_block(ptr)
    (f.close; return blah_nbr.to_i) if blah_nbr
  end
end

def read_block(ptr)
  @f.seek(ptr)
  @f.read(@chars_to_read)[/.*#{@blah_text}(\d+)/,1]
end
```

**Demo**

Let's first write something interesting to a file.

```
MY_FILE = 'my_file.txt'

text =<<_
Now is the time
for all blah2 to
come to the aid of
their blah3, blah4 enemy or
perhaps do blagh5 something
else like wash the dishes.
_

File.write(MY_FILE, text)
```

Now run the program:

```
p doit(MY_FILE, "blah") #=> 4
```

We expected it to return `4` and it did.

**Explanation**

`doit` first instructs `read_block` to read up to 37 characters, beginning `BLOCK_SIZE` (30) characters from the end of the file.  That's at the beginning of the string

```
"ng\nelse like wash the dishes.\n"
```

which is 30 characters long.  (I'll explain the "37" in a moment.)  `read_block` finds no text matching the regex (like "blah3"), so returns `nil`.

As `nil` was returned, `doit` makes the same request of `read_block`, but this time starting `BLOCK_SIZE` characters closer to the beginning of the file.  This time `read_block` reads the 37 character string:

```
"y or\nperhaps do blagh5 something\nelse"
```

but, again, does not match the regex, so returns `nil` to `doit`.  Notice that it read the seven characters, "ng\nelse", that it read previously.  This overlap is necessary in case one 30-character block ended, "...bla" and the next one began "h3...".  Hence the need to read more characters (here 37) than the block size.

`read_block` next reads the string:

```
"aid of\ntheir blah3, blah4 enemy or\npe"
```

and finds that "blah4" matches the regex (not "blah3", because the regex is being "greedy" with `.*`), so it returns `"4"` to `doit`, which converts that to the number `4`, which it returns.

`doit` would return `nil` if the regex did not match any text in the file.